# What's the usage of a "Cavity resonator" in a power supply circuit of a CD player?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, resonator

To diagnose a CD player I'm currently learning its schematics, yet I don't understand this part.
In the schematic, what could be the usage of PS401?

Thank you!

[image: Screenshot of the schematic]

Comment: That looks more like a jumper to me.  How did you get the idea that it is a cavity resonator?  Especially given that it is in the power input section of the device.

Comment: I don't think that that symbol represents a cavity resonator. Note the line connecting the circles - that is not present in a cavity resonator.

Comment: Can you provide a link to full schematic. I guess many of us like to see the US and UK model difference as whole. It must be bound to voltage and frequency differences and maybe also to different grounding practices. After it you can well extend the question to ask also these ideas. Forget the resonator, there's none!

Answer (score 3):

There is no 'cavity resonator'. The markings indicate the use of PS401 & a diode in the series regulator circuit for UK only. For other markets PS401 and the diode are bypassed. Of interest in this circuit is the diode-connected-transistor Q453.

PS401 appears to be a jumper, removing which would disconnect the negative terminal of the external 9V supply jack from ground and make it redundant.
In other words, removing the jumper would allow only battery operation of the CD player.

Comment: I agree but why would a UK model differ if it runs on batteries or 9V DC?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know.

Comment: Neither do I :-) I’m just curious. Perhaps same unregulated 9 V DC adapter throughout Europe and UK with 240 V had slightly higher input voltage?

Comment: Or to make it kid-safe? :-)